# CSS grids, how to color the area outside of grid

Tags: html, css

My grid:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 370px 1fr 1fr 1fr 370px;
  grid-template-areas:
  ". title title title ."
  ". about about about ."
  ". sidebar content content ."
  ". footer footer footer. ";
}
```

My about column:

```
.about {
  grid-area: about;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
```

I want to make it so that #EBEBEB is the background color for the entire `. about about about .` row. So, how do I make those 370px parts also grey?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify **[`grid-column-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-start)** and **[`grid-column-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end)** to control which sections are coloured. Assuming you're asking how you can make the **entire** row that holds the `.about` class grey, you're looking for `1` and `6` respectively:

```
.about {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 6;
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg-img {
  opacity: 0.95;
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27)), url(http://i.pi.gy/5mWAw.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 100px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 370px 1fr 1fr 1fr 370px;
  grid-template-areas: ". title title title ." ". about about about ." ". sidebar content content ." ". footer footer footer. ";
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.about {
  grid-area: about;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 6;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
  <h1 class="centered">Hi, I'm Karlo,<br>a Web Developer.</h1>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>My skills</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">Content
    <p>A</p>
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

And I've also created a new pen showcasing this **[here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaNozp)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!